# Excel custom number format for recurring decimal

Tags: excel, vba, decimal, recurring

I'm trying to make an auto roster spreadsheet with 5-3 and 6-2 weeks rotation, I have successfully used the 1.33 factor in the code below for the 6-2 weeks rotation.

```
   If OnSite = (Days * Format(1.33, "#,##0.0033333333333333")) + 1 Then
    OnSite = 1
   End If
```

But I can't get the desired result for 1.66 factor when using similar custom number format in 5-3 weeks rotation.

```
If OnSite = (Days * Format(1.66, "#,##0.0066666666666667")) + 1 Then
    OnSite = 1
   End If
```

Edit: Days = 35, I want to get a whole number only from Days x 1.66 to make the Onsite = 1

Comment: This must be a very wrong approach; numbers should be handled as numbers. What input do you have and what would the expected results be, please?

Comment: Hi @Gustav thank you for your follow-up question, date will be selected in the spreadsheet then a button will trigger the macro. ```

Comment: I see no date value here. What input do you have and what would the expected results be, please?

Comment: Roster will be highlighted from the date selected depending on roster button clicked (e.g. 6-2, 5-3). I think the custom number format is used to get the exact whole number, have tried to write Days x 1.6666666666666667 in code but VBA reduced it to 14 decimal places only.

Comment: Can I share the excel file on this forum so it would be easier to see the input and desired results?

Comment: It would be better if you told in plain English what you are trying to accomplish. Again, what values does `Days` hold, what does 5-3 or 6-2 rotation do, what results do you expect or need for `OnSite`?

Comment: @Gustav is right. You are not helping. You are not describing the overall problem you are having but you are hammering that something is wrong with getting a whole number. Please give the input you are having and the output you would expect related to the input. We want to help you, we can only do so with the right information.

Comment: Apologies for not giving enough information. I have edited my Question. Days = 35, I want to get a whole number only from Days x 1.66 to make the Onsite = 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have overlooked and focused to 1.66 factor but then I realized that I can get a whole number only from Days (35) x 1.6 = 56. Code below works perfectly now.

```
If OnSite = (Days * 1.6) + 1 Then
    OnSite = 1
   End If
``
```